# Is Preact testing library same as React testing library in terms of the testing the components?

Tags: react-testing-library, preact

The [documentation](https://preactjs.com/guide/v10/preact-testing-library/) from preact provides info that the preact-testing-library is a lightweight wrapper around preact/test-utils

The [documentation](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro/) from react provides info that react-testing-library is a lightweight wrapper around react-dom and react-dom/test-utils

Both looks like they should be used for testing components. Am I right? I'm a react/preact newbie, hence the question

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There is no "preact-dom" as Preact only targets the DOM, if that's what you were confused about.

Both can be used to test components.